# MagicalRecord NSManagedObject's don't save properly

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext, magicalrecord

I'm using `CoreData` with `MagicalRecord` and I've an issue with `NSManagedObjectContext's` though there is almost not using different threads for accessing entity, i.e  there is an entity `User` and scenario of creating/updating and using this entity is following:

1. When app starts call `[Database getCurrentUser:(User *user){
        .... 
        // Here comes some logic to choose rootViewController depends on data inside entity
        // if there is no any entities of User, this method creates a new one
      }]`
2. If there were created a new entity of `User` open VC with authorization
3. When user enter his data and press button to authorize call method `[self authorizeWithCode:%code%];`
      Inside this method I'm getting data using REST API. My request is executes on the background thread and
      response is coming on the main thread.
4. After getting data from network, call `[Database updateUserData:%data% completion:(BOOL success){
        // See implementation below
        // if success == YES call [self getCitiesList];
      }];`
5. As you can see method `[self getCitiesList]` calls method `[Api getCitiesList:^(BOOL success, NSDictionary *responseObject, NSError *error){}];` which is working such as  `[self authorizeWithCode:%code%];` (I mean threading) but to get data with this method I must put two parameters inside request body. To achieve this I'm trying to get the entity that had been saved in `[Database updateUserData:%data% completion:(BOOL success){}];` but every time I do it, I'm getting empty entity though `NSLog` prints succesful saving message.
   I tried to print out all entities of `User` and was surprised. There was 8 different entities! The main idea is that there must be one and only one entity of `User`.

What am I doing wrong? What a proper way to get updated entity and not create a new one every time I'm trying update existing?

**Database.m methods:**

```
+(void)getCurrentUser:(void (^)(User *))user{
    __block User *currentUser = [User MR_findFirstInContext:[NSManagedObjectContext MR_defaultContext]];
    if(!currentUser){
        [MagicalRecord saveWithBlock:^(NSManagedObjectContext *localContext) {
            User *newUser = [User MR_createEntityInContext:localContext];
            currentUser = newUser;
        } completion:^(BOOL contextDidSave, NSError *error) {
            user(currentUser);
        }];
    } else {
        user(currentUser);
    }
}

+(void)updateUserData:(NSDictionary *)data completion:(void (^)(BOOL success))completion{
      User *user = [User MR_findFirstInContext:[NSManagedObjectContext MR_defaultContext]];
        [MagicalRecord saveWithBlock:^(NSManagedObjectContext *localContext) {
            User *currentUser = [user MR_inContext:localContext];
            currentUser = [User MR_importFromObject:data inContext:localContext];
        } completion:^(BOOL contextDidSave, NSError *error) {
            completion(contextDidSave);
        }];
}
```

**Api.m `getCitiesList` method:**

```
+(void)getCitiesList:(Completion)completion{
        User *currentUser = [User MR_findFirstInContext:[NSManagedObjectContext MR_context]];
        DEFAULT_BACKGROUND_THREAD_BLOCK
        [NetworkManager GET:FormatString(@"%@%@",BASE_URL,GET_CITIES_URL) params:@{kPhoneKey:currentUser.phone,kTokenKey:currentUser.access_token} completion:^(BOOL success, NSDictionary *responseObject, NSError *error) {
        if(success && responseObject){
            ...
        }
        MAIN_THREAD_BLOCK
        completion(success,responseObject,error);
        END_THREAD_BLOCK
        }];
        END_THREAD_BLOCK
}
```

**AuthVC.m methods:**

```
-(void)authorizeWithCode:(NSString *)code{
[SVProgressHUD showWithStatus:@"Authorize" maskType:SVProgressHUDMaskTypeBlack];
[Api authorizeUseithPhone:_phoneNumber andCode:code completion:^(BOOL success, NSDictionary *responseObject, NSError *error) {
    MAIN_THREAD_BLOCK
    if(!error){
        if(success){
            if(responseObject){
                userInfo = responseObject;
                [Database updateUserData:userInfo completion:^(BOOL success) {
                    if(success){
                      [self getCitiesList];
                    }
                }];
            }
        }
        else{
            [SVProgressHUD dismiss];
            NSLog(@"unsuccessful result is %@",responseObject);
        }
    } else {
        [SVProgressHUD dismiss];
        [Api showErrorInController:self withMessage:error.localizedDescription];
    }
    END_THREAD_BLOCK
}];
}

-(void)getCitiesList{
[SVProgressHUD showWithStatus:@"Getting cities list"];
[Api getCitiesList:^(BOOL success, NSDictionary *responseObject, NSError *error) {
    MAIN_THREAD_BLOCK
    if(!error){
        if(success){
            if(responseObject){
                ...
            }
        }  else{
            [SVProgressHUD dismiss];
            NSLog(@"unsuccessful result is %@",responseObject);
        }
    } else {
        [SVProgressHUD dismiss];
        [Api showErrorInController:self withMessage:error.localizedDescription];
    }
    END_THREAD_BLOCK
}];
}
```

Comment: Depends how long the users have existed, is this a development issue or a real issue. Delete the data store and start fresh testing to check.

Comment: @Wain there is absolutely empty data store and nothing changes

Comment: You said there were 8 users in the store. Please explain your full test scenario and debugging.